# Using Sphinx docs how can I specify png image formats for HTML builds and pdf image formats for Latex/PDF builds?

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, documentation-generation, python-sphinx

Using sphinx doc generator, I am trying to use .png images for the HTML builds of the documentation, and then I want to have the .svg images used for the PDF/LATEx builds.

Anyone know how to "tag" sections as "HTML build"-only and "Latex build"-only?

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at these options:

1. Image filename wildcard:

   ```
   .. image:: gnu.*
   ```

   From the [documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images): "For instance, if the file name gnu.* was given and two files gnu.pdf and gnu.png existed in the source tree, the LaTeX builder would choose the former, while the HTML builder would prefer the latter."
2. The [`only`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-only) directive:

   ```
   .. only:: latex

      This appears only in LaTeX output.

   .. only:: html

      This appears only in HTML output.
   ```

Comment: Thanks @mzjn

    .. only:: 

is exactly what I was looking for :)

I remember seeing it in the docs and thinking I would need it someday and then I promptly forgot it and couldn't find it again!

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect!  This works for having the HTML builder use an SVG, and LaTeX to use a PDF as an image.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use the makefile to automatically build the appropriate output formats.

A tutorial demonstrating a similar process for [using Sphinx with SVG and LaTeX PDF output](http://sites.google.com/site/nickfolse/home/sphinx-latexpdf-output-with-svg-images) is also available.

1. Use the image [filename wildcard option](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#images) in your .rst source.

   ```
   .. image:: my_image.*
   ```
2. Use Inkscape to convert your source images into PDFs and PNGs at build-time.  You can do this automatically at build-time by adding the following code to your Makefile:

   ```
   SOURCEDIR     = source
   #IMAGEDIRS can be a list of directories that contain SVG files and are relative to the SOURCEDIR
   IMAGEDIRS      = _images

   # SVG to PDF conversion
   SVG2PDF       = inkscape
   SVG2PDF_FLAGS = -C

   # SVG to PNG conversion
   SVG2PNG       = inkscape
   SVG2PNG_FLAGS = -C -d=90 --export-background-opacity=\#00

   # Pattern rule for converting SVG to PDF
   %.pdf : %.svg
       $(SVG2PDF) $(SVG2PDF_FLAGS) -f $< -A $@

   # Pattern rule for converting SVG to PNG
   %.png : %.svg
       $(SVG2PNG) $(SVG2PNG_FLAGS) -f $< -e $@

   # Build a list of SVG files to convert to PDFs
   PDFs := $(foreach dir, $(IMAGEDIRS), $(patsubst %.svg,%.pdf,$(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/$(dir)/*.svg)))

   # Build a list of SVG files to convert to PNGs
   PNGs := $(foreach dir, $(IMAGEDIRS), $(patsubst %.svg,%.png,$(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/$(dir)/*.svg)))

   # Make a rule to build the PDFs
   images-pdf: $(PDFs) 

   # Make a rule to build the PNGs
   images-png: $(PNGs) 

   # Make a rule to build the images
   images: images-pdf images-png

   clean-pdf:
       -rm $(PDFs)

   clean-png:
       -rm $(PNGs)

   clean-images: clean-pdf clean-png
   ```

   Finally, update the `clean`, `latex` and `latexpdf` rules to have a dependency on the respective image targets:

   ```
   ...
   clean: clean-images
   ...
   html: images-png
   ... 
   latex: images-pdf
   ...
   latexpdf: images-pdf
   ...
   ```

   Now you can build your images by typing `make images` and clean them with `make clean-images`.  Using `make html`, `make latex` and `make latexpdf` will automatically make sure your images are up-to-date.
3. One problem is that Sphinx defaults to preferring SVG over PNG in HTML output.  You can fix this by overriding preferece in your `conf.py` file.

   Add the following lines near the top of your `conf.py` file, after imports.

   ```
   # Redefine supported_image_types for the HTML builder
   from sphinx.builders.html import StandaloneHTMLBuilder
   StandaloneHTMLBuilder.supported_image_types = ['image/png', 'image/svg+xml', 
                                          'image/gif', 'image/jpeg']
   ```