# Sphinx documentation: Include svg images in PDFs via latex

Tags: pdf, svg, latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I'm doing an internship for an IT company which needs a document application for its firmware docs (md files).

The request was to maintain these md files and to convert them to rst format (I used pandoc). So now I have a configured Sphinx application with only rst files. The problem now is that some rst have links to SVG images, and I have to use the latex builder of Sphinx to convert them to PDFs.

I've searched around and I found this solution from 2 years ago, which was essentially what I was looking for: https://sites.google.com/site/nickfolse/home/sphinx-latexpdf-output-with-svg-images. I tried to implement it but I'm not an expert with GNU makefiles and I don't know if the current version of Sphinx allows it or if it is out there an easy workaround, so the thing didn't succeed.

Does someone have a viable solution for this?

Comment: Can you expand on "so the thing did not succeed"? What exactly did you try?

Comment: Of course. I tried to modify the Makefile in the main directory of the project as shown in https://sites.google.com/site/nickfolse/home/sphinx-latexpdf-output-with-svg-images  and in this previous answered question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541474/8172391 but, maybe for my lack of knowledge of Makefiles or other things, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, SVG is still not supported. I work around it in Pyramid docs by exporting the original file (OmniGraffle) to both SVG and PNG.

In [docs/narr/router.rst](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blame/master/docs/narr/router.rst#L12):

```
.. image:: ../_static/pyramid_request_processing.*
```

And we place images in [docs/_static](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs/_static).

The [HTML uses SVG](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/router.html) and the [PDF uses PNG](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid/downloads/pdf/latest/).

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful! I didn't thought that the .*  extension would work without any workarounds. Probably I will implement this solution.

Comment: @VahnIronSky Please accept it as the correct answer, if it is so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is available the [Sphinx SVG to PDF converter](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-svg2pdfconverter/) extension to automatically convert from SVG to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Since Sphinx 1.6 version you can use bundled extension [sphinx.ext.imgconverter](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/imgconverter.html) for automatic conversion your SVG into PNG:

1. Open your `source/conf.py` and add to `extensions` variable this string:

   ```py
   extensions = [
       'sphinx.ext.imgconverter',
   ]
   ```
2. Run build:

   ```bash
   make latexpdf
   ```