# Using Sphinx Extension to convert svg to pdf

Tags: imagemagick, latex, python-sphinx, imagemagick-convert, pdflatex

My company is using Sphinx to create the manuals for our products. Our products are shipped with PDF and HTML documentations. We are using Windows as a sole developer environment.

A necessary requirement is to generate both kind of format from the same sources (*.rst files).

A legacy documentation uses extensive SVG-Images, but the sphinx build format `latex` does not support SVG-Files in `\includegraphics{}` environments.

Now I found the promising Sphinx-Extension `sphinx.ext.imgconverter` and included it into my `conf.py`.

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.imgmath',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.imgconverter'
]
```

Hopefully, converting all SVG-Files into PDF-files if I'm building LaTeX. Unfortunately, the documentation of the extension is very short and there is no working example.

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/imgconverter.html#module-sphinx.ext.imgconverter

The contents of our rst files are basically:

```
.. image:: Image.*
   :width: 100px
```

Sphinx should figure out on its own, if the star should be replcaced by svg or pdf depending on the build html/pdf. This information I got from previous posts:

1. [Using Sphinx docs how can I specify png image formats for HTML builds and pdf image formats for Latex/PDF builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473660/5762796)

But somehow there I'm unable to generate my latex.
[Using Sphinx docs how can I specify png image formats for HTML builds and pdf image formats for Latex/PDF builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473660/5762796)

Instead the following warning is issued:

```
WARNING: no matching candidate for image URI u'Image.*'
```

But only if I wanted to build LaTeX in case of HTML there is no warning.

Do I have to install ImageMagick or is there is something wrong? How does Sphinx know, where to search ImageMagick?

**Update**

I just updated my Sphinx to version 1.7.2. It still doesn't work. As I was unable to install ImageMagick, I temporarily removed the extension `sphinx.ext.imgconverter` from my `conf.py` to test for a manual solution. I converted all the images manually to pdf/png using inkscape.

Now I got the following warnings, if I compile with `make latex`.

```
WARNING: a suitable image for latex builder not found: ['image/svg+xml']
```

But there are definitely manually converted images (pdf,png) in both the `source` directory and the `build/latex` directory, alike.

My LaTeX file is compiled to something like:

```
\noindent\sphinxincludegraphics[width=100\sphinxpxdimen]{{Image}.*}
```

And I'm unable to compile it with pdflatex.

```
LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .*.
```

Are there some settings for the LaTeX Builder in my `conf.py` to take my converted images?

If I include the following lines in my `conf.py` something unexpected happens:

```
from sphinx.builders.latex import LaTeXBuilder
LaTeXBuilder.supported_image_types = ['image/png', 'image/pdf','image/svg+xml' ]
```

The output of my LaTeX file now contains the line:

```
\noindent\sphinxincludegraphics[width=100\sphinxpxdimen]{{Image}.svg}
```

If I remove the type `image/svg+xml` from the `supported_image_types` I got the previous error again. My impression is, that `sphinx-build` looks for the converted images in the wrong places. But this is just an idea.

Comment: check out [sphinxcontrib-svg2pdfconverter](https://github.com/sephalon/sphinxcontrib-svg2pdfconverter) which will help convert on the fly svg's to pdf's for  usage with latex builder of Sphinx. It is based on [sphinx.ext.imgconverter](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/imgconverter.html#module-sphinx.ext.imgconverter) to add conversion via inkscape or rsvg-convert

Answer (score 4):

#### Scaling scholars select svg2pdfconverter

If you want really high-quality embedded images in your Sphinx-latexpdf-generated documents, @user4184837's suggestion of using `sphinx-svg2pdfconverter` is absolutely the way to go, because it does Just What It Says On The Tin™: It converts your SVG files to small embeddable *PDF* documents which retain their scalability! The vectors never get rasterized anywhere in the output pipeline, so they're sharp and clear at any size.

#### Installation and selection of rendering backend

To get the Sphinx extension you can just `pip install sphinxcontrib-svg2pdfconverter`, but you'll also need an SVG interpreter/converter backend. (The extension only handles the Sphinx end of things.) Currently, three are supported:

1. **Inkscape**, which requires you to install... well... all of Inkscape.
2. The **`rsvg-convert`** command-line tool, which can be installed from the appropriate distro package on Linux, or acquired by other means. (The package is spelled `librsvg2-bin` in the Debian universe, whereas those more partial to crimson headwear pronounce it `librsvg2-tools`.)
3. Lightest-weight of all, you can just install **`cairosvg`**, a Python package  you can just install from PyPi at the same time as the extension itself. Svg2pdfconverter has a couple of additional dependencies when using Cairosvg, so you'll want to install it as `sphinxcontrib-svg2pdfconverter[Cairosvg]`.

At least for my relatively simple graphics of toolbar-icon-level complexity, the choice of backend makes no discernible difference in the output. So, obviously Cairosvg is the path of least resistance there. It's as simple as inserting it into your list of Python package dependencies.

Cairosvg isn't *actually* implemented exclusively in Python, but it ***is*** a pure-Python PyPi package. As the name implies, it's based on Cairo, and uses `cffi` to `dlopen()` and interface with an available `libcairo.so` / `libcairo.dylib` / `libcairo.dll`.

Cairosvg won't **install** libcairo if you don't have it, but it's pretty ubiquitous:

- It's ***hard*** to find a Linux system without cairo as a system package.
- On macOS, it picked up an existing `/usr/local/lib/libcairo.dylib`; Homebrew says it was installed as a dependency of ffmpeg. And opencv. And gtk+3. And...
- Windows is slightly harder, but if you've installed MSYS2 you already have a `libcairo.dll` in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\`. Even in `cmd.exe`/`pwsh.exe`, add that dir to your path and cairosvg will pick up the DLL.

You can confirm it sees the library by just importing its cffi interface:

```py
>>> import cairocffi
>>> # If you DON'T see any error messages, you're good to go
>>> # or confirm and check the library location with...
>>> cairocffi.cairo
<Lib object for '/usr/local/lib/libcairo.dylib'>
```

#### Putting it all together

There is some configuration possible with svg2pdfconverter, but it's very likely you won't need it, at least initially. It absolutely *will* just work right out of the box, with zero config beyond adding it to the `extensions` list in your `conf.py`.

You choose the backend to use by the extension class you add:

- `sphinxcontrib.inkscapeconverter`
- `sphinxcontrib.rsvgconverter`
- `sphinxcontrib.cairosvgconverter`

Pick the one you have the necessary dependencies for, and you're off to the races.

More likely what you'll need to adjust are your SVG files, slightly, so that they're better suited to embedding in your Sphinx documents.

##### I hate to break it to you, but: size matters

The first issue is layout — if you want to place SVG images inline with your text content, you'll need to scale and frame them accordingly. A `16px` square icon is probably the maximum size you'd want to use inline, and evne that's going to overpower the surrounding text a bit. If you import a `128px` square icon design instead, it **will** be proportionally eight times larger, and your body text will be interrupted by a dropped-in graphic that takes up nearly half the page.

You'll probably also want to design inline SVG images so they're aligned to the very bottom center of their bounding box, with a fair amount of space remaining above. An inline embedded SVG sits directly on the text baseline, extending only upward as its size increases. So any padding below just makes it look even more awkward, while you need padding above because the top of the image's bounding box will dictate the height of that line of text.

When I originally imported the SVG icons for our documentation (well, after I *re*-imported them, scaled down from `256px` square to `16px`!) they all had shrink-wrapped bounding boxes. In the final PDF every SVG image that ended up in the first line of text for a table cell was wearing the border line above it for a hat.

Realigning the graphics so they were roughly `12px` wide by no taller than `14px`, sitting at the bottom of a `16px` square page area:

[image: plus-sign icon laid out on an Inkscape canvas, with empty space on three sides, but no gap along the bottom edge]

...created a little breathing room:

[image: zoomed-in detail of a rendered PDF, showing text with an SVG icon embedded inline]

And that's pretty much that!

Answer (score 1):

1. I suspect that the error is related to this [issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4720).  It was fixed in Sphinx 1.7, which indicates you have a release of Sphinx < 1.7 installeed.  Upgrade to Sphinx 1.7 or greater.  **Tip:** always search the source code repository for help.
2. From the documentation for [`sphinx.ext.imgconverter`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/imgconverter.html#module-sphinx.ext.imgconverter):

   > Internally, this extension uses [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert images.

   Which means it must be installed and be in your system path.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have sphinx-build 1.7.0 installed. I'll try for updates.